# long delay AsyncTask and restart task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would like to implement this function:
When the user click on button start the task and after 5 minute send one file to dropbox, but if the user click another time on the button, the precedent task abort and new task (5 min) start.

I wrote code to upload files to Dropbox, but never written code using task with such a long time (5 minute).
How can do that?

**-- EDIT --**

thanks @xdevs23, I have implemented the final code

```
public void onSendOrder() {

        try {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(postRunnable); // stop current wait
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            // Just if the above fails (might be first time)
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        int minutes = 5;
        mHandler.postDelayed(postRunnable, minutes * 20 * 1000 /* 5 minutes in milliseconds */);
...
...
...

private Runnable postRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
            myThread.start();
        }
    };


    private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your code
                int cloud = GetPreferenceCloud();
                if(cloud > 0){
                    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    final File bckDatabase = BackupDatabase();

                    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() && bckDatabase != null) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // call your asynctask here
                            new UploadOnCloud(MainActivity.this,
                                    PreferenceConstants.DB_DATABASE_STORE_CLOUD,
                                    PreferenceConstants.FILE_DIR_CLOUD,
                                    bckDatabase,
                                    mUListener,
                                    cloud).execute();
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.send_msg13), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

*** EDIT. V2 ***

For implement the Countdown on statusbar I've implemented this:

Modify the onSend function:

```
public void onSendOrder() {

        try {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(postRunnable); // stop current wait
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            // Just if the above fails (might be first time)
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        minute = 3600;
        //mHandler.postDelayed(postRunnable, minutes * 20 * 1000 /* 5 minutes in milliseconds */);
        mHandler.postDelayed(postRunnable, 1000 /* 1 seconds */);
```

....
....

in the file menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/break_timer"
          android:title="00:00"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_autorenew"/>
</menu>
```

modify the onCreateOptionsMenu

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem timerItem = menu.findItem(R.id.break_timer);
        timerText = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(timerItem);
        timerText.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0); //Or something like that...

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


private int minute;
    private Runnable postRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(minute >= 0){
                minute--;
                mHandler.postDelayed(postRunnable, 1000 /* 1 seconds */);
                timerText.setText(secondsToString(minute));
            }else {
                Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
                myThread.start();
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `AsyncTask`, you could use `Thread`s and `Runnable`s.

Create a `Runnable` where your code, which you want to run in the background, is located:

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Create your `Thread`:

```
private Thread myThread;
```

Make sure that you have a handler created on **the main thread**.
For best results, add it to your `onCreate()` method:

```
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // ...
    mHandler = new Handler();
    // ...
}
```

You need to import `android.os.Handler`.

Declare the runnable where your upload code is:

```
private Runnable postRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Now do following when the user clicks on the button:

```
try {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(postRunnable); // stop current wait
} catch(Exception ex) {
    // Just if the above fails (might be first time)
}
int minutes = 5;
mHandler.postDelayed(postRunnable, minutes * 60 * 1000 /* 5 minutes in milliseconds */);
```

And that's it.

**Explanation:**

When the user clicks on the button, it will wait (without blocking the UI) for 5 seconds, and then it will run the code inside `postRunnable`, which starts a new thread in the background, which will run the code inside your `myRunnable`.

**Edit for updating notification**

```
private Handler mHandler;
private int minutes = 5;
private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(minutes > 0) {
            String notifContent = "" + minutes + " remaining.";
            // Create your notification (there are several guides which show you how to do this), use notifContent as title or text or whatsoever
            minutes--;
            mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 60 * 1000);
        } else {
            // Remove your notification
        }
    }
};
```

To start the countdown:

```
mHandler.post(updateRunnable);
```

Comment: I would like to implement a down-counter in the statusbar to show how much minute/second remain to before send file to server...

Comment: You could create one more thread with a runnable which will run **every minute** and count down the `int minutes` variable whenever the runnable is run. In the runnable, you can then show a notification, for example, with the current `int minutes` value.

Comment: in practice i have to substitude the:
mHandler.postDelayed(postRunnable, minutes * 20 * 1000 /* 5 minutes in milliseconds */);
whit a thread runnable? I have tried whith CountDownTimer and override the onTick method, but dont' work!

Comment: I have implemented, (see my EDIT V2) , without using new thread.

Comment: I have edited the answer again to use the countdown without a separate thread. I have noticed that it's not even necessary having a separate thread for that kind of stuff.